# Calling Library (guzzle) for php web crawler?

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

I have a php web crawler to parse the selective statements from the site mentioned.

it was working fine but when i added a while loop to it to parse multiple pages of the site, it came error as `Warning: require_once(github.com/guzzle/guzzle): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

i did downloaded the guzzle folder from `https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle`
but still seems like the correct identification is not done properly in my script;

My script goes as:

```
<?php
    $i = 1; 
    while(true){ 
    require_once('github.com/guzzle/guzzle');
    $subject = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1&Page='+$i);
    preg_match_all('/<td.+?FootNotes2.+?<a.+?<\/a> - (?P<name>.*?)<\/td>.+?<td.+?FootNotes2.+?(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})/siu', $subject, $matchs); 

    foreach ($matchs['name'] as $v){ 
    echo $v. " "; 
    } 
    foreach ($matchs['date'] as $v){ 
    echo $v. " "; 
    } 
    }
    $i++; 
?>
```

what actually supposed to return is to print the text with tag as name and text as date for all the pages in the site,

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your folder, or put the files in shortest path. And `require_once()` is to require files not folder

Comment: what should i name the folder
?

Comment: Like you want, but require_once is only for files ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: actually i did worked the same code without `require_once or guzzle` and that `while loop`, it worked fine.. but then i added while loop to get data from all pages, then it showed an error, so a friend suggested to add this guzzle thing.. i pretty new to this?\

Comment: @please help me with this one line over there.. should i download the files from github guzzle or should i not?

Comment: Maybe you should add limit for your while loop, because she run forever. And if you want to use Guzzle there's doc to help you ( http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: dude, please man, just tell me whether i should download that file or not?

Comment: If you want to use Guzzle, you have to download it (from Composer its easier) , everything is wrote in the doc

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II can you help me on this

Comment: ok ... so i downloaded the guzzle from the mentioned github link.. now i extracted the zip, then i see lot of folders./// now i what path should i mention in the `require_once` tag?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII can you help me on this

Comment: Now run in Guzzle folder, 'composer install' and after this, you add to your code 'require 'vendor/autoload.php''

Comment: the composer file in guzzle-master folder is a .json file bro, when i click it, it opens in visual studio.

Comment: Follow these instructions http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation